# Python 2.7 NUMPY ImportError: PyCapsule_Import could not import module "date time" in mac version 10.11

Tags: python, macos, numpy, terminal, sublimetext3

I am using Python 2.7 and Sublime Text 3. 
I ran this code in terminal, and it ran well but when I try to run it using Sublime Text, it doesn't.

TERMINAL MODE:

```
Last login: Wed Mar 23 11:16:23 on ttys000
admins-iMac:~ admin$ python
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (x86_64)| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:57:58) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
import numpy
numbers = [1,5,6,7,8,9]
numpy.mean(numbers)
6.0
```

SUBLIME TEXT MODE

RESPONSE FROM SUBLIME TEXT:

```
ImportError: PyCapsule_Import could not import module "date time"
```

Comment: the code in terminal is Last login: Wed Mar 23 11:16:23 on ttys000
admins-iMac:~ admin$ python
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (x86_64)| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:57:58) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import numpy
>>> numbers = [1,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> numpy.mean(numbers)
6.0
>>>

Comment: Have you set up Sublime to use Anaconda in your build system?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to find an answer through some guidance from Stephen, that if you rename the file it works. Somehow having the file name as Numbers.py doesn't work. So renamed as test.py. Sound simple, it worked, after a week time of difficulty. thanks everyone

Comment: Thank you very much Mr.Halfer